# Text Icon Transparency issue with SVG file

Tags: svg, javafx

I am trying to create a simple SVG icon (composite path) using Adobe Fireworks.
Icon shall comprise of a circle with an alphabet in its centre.
The background of circle is supposed to be transparent but that of that should be would be the outline color of circle.
When i am trying to merge both elements as composite path using Join then the text fill is lost.

Icon is supposed to be a Single Composite Path only as it is then required to be imported in my Javafx application.

I am attaching both expected icon and current icon being created for understanding issue
[image: Expected Icon]

[image: Current Created Icon]

Any possible solution for same would be really helpful
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try [inkscape](http://inkscape.org) and edit your svg's source file with an ascii editor!

Comment: What is your desktop (system)?